# Помогите решить задание на C#

Tags: c#

Даны целые числа а1, а2, …, а45 . Вычислить сумму положительных членов последовательности а1, а2, … а30 и число нулевых членов всей последовательности а1, а2, …, а45.

Comment: Stackoverflow не место чтобы за вас решали задачи. Привидите фрагмент кода где у вас появился вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Ну и ужас...Держи, разберись что и как работает и больше не задавай такие вопросы. Все элементарно просто

```
var random = new Random();
var nums = new int[45];
for (var i = 0; i < 45; i++)
{
    nums[i] = random.Next(-10, 10);
}

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    if (nums[i] > 0)
    {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
}

var countZero = nums.Count(num => num == 0);
```